# Sub form opens before the main form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form contains two sub forms created in MS Access. There are two text boxes on the main form. After the user enters the start and end dates in the text boxes, and clicks on the search button, the information in these two sub forms should be recalculated and refreshed the results on the sub forms and showed within the main form.

Once, I changed the data source for one sub form and saved it, I don’t know whether it caused the problem. Now, after the user enters the dates, and search the result, one of the sub form opens by itself first with correct result. After the user closes this sub form, the main form with two sub forms display with the correct results.

How can I stop the first sub form popping up first, just show main form with two sub forms together?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: delete the data source for the sub form.

Comment: A data source does not open a form. You must have changed the code of the search buton.

Comment: Show the code behind the search button to get good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked on the popping open result again, accurately, it is the result of a query1 which I changed once before to replace the original sub form record source, not the sub form itself popping open. Now I use a new query2 for this sub form's record source. I didn't change any code for search button. In some reason, the program always remembers the query1and popping up after clicking the search button before the main form with the sub forms show even through the current record source for this sub form is query2. How can I stop this popping up query1 to show?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Subform always opens before the main form, see below for form events order. To avoid subform popping up first, you can set the subform recordsource as null on form load.

[Order of events for database objects](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. accurately, it is the result of a query1 which I changed once before to replace the original sub form record source, not the sub form itself popping open. Sorry. please see my details above, your feedback is very much appreciated!

Comment: When I replaced the original record source for the sub form, I changed on the sub form directly and saved the change, not worked within the main form. did that cost the problem?

Comment: I will recommend you to first clear the record source property of subforms and instead set in on click of a button. Try this, if not show your code so that we can help.

Comment: Private sub Output_Results_Click()
‘Delete query to delete all records in the Output table
DoCmd.OpenQuery “Output_Records_Del”
‘Append query uploading new records to the Output table based on the dates that user entered in the Start and End date text boxed.
DoCmd.OpenQuery “Output_Records_App
‘Delete query to delete all records in the Output Total table
DoCmd.OpenQuery “Output_Total_Del”
‘Append crosstab query to the Output Total table
DoCmd.OpenQuery “Output_Total_App”
‘Refresh subforms
[Output_Records subform].Requery
[Output_Total subform].Requery
End Sub

Comment: The crosstab always popping up before the main form opens. I have tied to clean up the record source on the sub form property and vba code in the search button for the sub form record source, but the same thing happened again. Any advice?

Comment: @Jane  Can you upload your file on the shared drive and share?